# Generating random values in python

Tags: python, list, random, python-3.x

I need to generate 100 random values between 0 and 500 and store the even values in a list and the odd in an other one. I am stuck in the beginning.

```
import random

def randomval():

   size=random.randint(0, 500)
   return 
   if val%2==0:
       listeven.append()
   else:
       listodd.append()
```

Comment: And what have you tried to test if a value is odd or even? Or are you stuck because the `randomval()` function doesn't return what you expected to get?

Comment: you have to `return size`. then call `randomval()` function 100 times. then you are done.

Comment: (Sorry I'm lazy and just posted a solution; probably just hinting on what is to be done would have been better at this looking-like-homework question.)

Comment: That's already a lot better, the `return` is now in the way and you seem to have forgotten to include a loop, but it's more of an attempt at coding it yourself now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
both = [ random.randint(0, 500) for i in range(100) ]
odd = [ x for x in both if x % 2 == 1 ]
even = [ x for x in both if x % 2 == 0 ]
```

Comment: please fix if statements

Comment: ```x & 1``` is usually slightly faster, despite being less obvious.

Comment: Yeah I had mixed `& 1` and `% 2` unsuccessfully ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Do it all in One Pass - much more efficient.

```
from random import randint

even, odd = [], []
for _ in range(100):
    num = randint(0, 500)
    if num % 2:
        odd.append(num)
    else:
        even.append(num)
```

As a function:

```
def get_random_even_and_odd(amount=100, _min=0, _max=500):
    even, odd = [], []
    for _ in range(amount):
        num = randint(_min, _max)
        if num % 2:
            odd.append(num)
        else:
            even.append(num)
    return even, odd
```

Comment: Ick, don't use conditional expressions when you should really use an `if` statement. Just use `if num % 2: odd.append(num)`, `else: even.append(num)`. If you *have* to use a one-liner, `odd if num % 2 else even).append(num)` is possibly uglier but at least you use the conditional expression as an actual expression for its own sake.

Comment: Generally right, @MartijnPieters, but I see a trade-off if using the `if` statement would mean to double the code massively.  In this case it is just the `.append(num)` which gets doubled so it doesn't matter that much, but if that part is larger, then I'd prefer the conditional expression you proposed.

Comment: @Alfe: Don't confuse one-liners with readability. Using a conditional expression creates certain expectations, namely that the outcome of the whole expression is to be used for something. Instead, Inbar was just using it for the side effects (one of two mutables changed).

Comment: Of course, the Inbar way (so to speak) was an abuse.  I only compared statements (four lines, doubled code) to conditional (one line as you proposed it).  And, btw, conditionals can be spread over several lines to increase readability.  Did a lot of functional programming earlier, have gotten used to it.  But of course, aspects like code-doubling or more objective than readability.

Answer (score 2):

Solution depends on whether random number can be repeated or no.

```
random_values = [ random.randint(0, 500) for i in range(100) ]
odd = [ x for x in random_values if x % 2 ]
even = [ x for x in random_values if not x % 2 ]
```

And If You would like to get unique random number I would propose You to use shuffle

```
random_values = random.sample(range(0, 500), 100)
odd = [ x for x in random_values if x % 2 ]
even = [ x for x in random_values if not x % 2 ]
```

You can reduce memory usage using generators for example

```
random_values = (random.randint(0, 500) for i in xrange(100))
odd = []
even = []
for val in random_values:
    if val % 2:
        odd.append(val)
    else:
        even.append(val)
```